# Clicking on a button in Safari using AppleScript

Tags: safari, applescript, web-browser

I know there are several topics with tutorials for clicking links/buttons on webpages with AppleScript, but unfortunately none of them worked for me on this specific website.

The website contains animated slides (realised with JW Player) and only when the slide (each one takes 30s - 90s) has finished, you are able to press "Next" to get to the next slide.

Here is a picture of the buttons:

[image]

And there's the HTML-Structure of the buttons:

```
<div class="controls default-controls">
        <a class="btn btn-dark player-back">
        <i class="icon wb-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"><i>
        <span>Back</span>
        </a>

        <a class="btn btn-dark player-next btn-primary">
        <span>Next</span>
        <i class="icon wb-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
</div>
```

Here is the AppleScript which works fine on other sites but not on this one.

```
tell application "Safari"

activate
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('player-next')[0].click();" in current tab of window 1
end tell
```

How can I simulate a button press (so the JavaScript behind it will be executed)?

Comment: What is the actual URL of the webpage containing this content?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't access this website because it is constructed to work only with aviation companies (you need a verified account) for the training of their employees/pilots. :/

Does it help if I upload a screen recording with the problem and the html code shown?

Greetings Raphael